# change state radio button if image is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two radio buttons and each radio button has an image. Now I want that if you click on a image that also the state of the radio button changed. This is the html code:

```
        @if (Html.GebruikerContext().Klant.LogoIDSpecified)
        {
            <div class="property wide extra-margin">
                <label>
                    Kies header logo
                </label>
                <div class="email-logo">
                    <div class="email-logo-image">
                        <a href=""> <img src='/Beheer/Images/mainlogo_274x122.png' />      </a>


                        <div class="email-logo-button">
                            <label>
                                @Html.RadioButton("logo-selectie", "standaard", !Model.GebruikKlantLogo, new { @name = "logoKeuze" })
                                <span>standaard logo</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>



                <div class="email-logo">
                    <div class="email-logo-image">
                        <img src='/Beheer/Document/Download?documentID=@(Html.GebruikerContext().Klant.LogoID)' />
                    </div>
                    <div class="email-logo-button">
                        <label>
                            @Html.RadioButton("logo-selectie", "klant", Model.GebruikKlantLogo, new { @name = "logoKeuze" })
                            <span>eigen logo</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

and this is the javascript code for the radio button:

```
 $('#logo-selectie[value=standaard]').click(function () {
            $('#GebruikKlantLogo').val(false);
        });

        $('#logo-selectie[value=klant]').click(function () {
            $('#GebruikKlantLogo').val(true);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way which involves no JS code would be to modify your HTML so that the `<label>` element wraps both the radio button and the image, something like this:

```html
<div class="property wide extra-margin">
  <label>
    Kies header logo
  </label>
  <div class="email-logo">
    <div class="email-logo-image">
      <label>
        <img src='/Beheer/Images/mainlogo_274x122.png' />
        <div class="email-logo-button">
          @Html.RadioButton("logo-selectie", "standaard", !Model.GebruikKlantLogo, new { @name = "logoKeuze" })
          <span>standaard logo</span> 
        </div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="email-logo">
    <label>
      <div class="email-logo-image">
        <img src='/Beheer/Document/Download?documentID=@(Html.GebruikerContext().Klant.LogoID)' />
      </div>
      <div class="email-logo-button">
        @Html.RadioButton("logo-selectie", "klant", Model.GebruikKlantLogo, new { @name = "logoKeuze" })
        <span>eigen logo</span>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can then amend your jQuery event handlers to use the `change` event instead, which is better for accessibility anyway:

```
$('#logo-selectie[value=standaard]').change(function () {
  $('#GebruikKlantLogo').val(false);
});

$('#logo-selectie[value=klant]').change(function () {
  $('#GebruikKlantLogo').val(true);
});
```

Comment: But I get the message div cannot be nested in element label

Comment: In which case you could change them to `span` elements. If needed, you can set `display: block` on them in CSS to keep the document flow.

Comment: You mean label replaced with span?

Comment: <span>

                                <img src='/Beheer/Images/mainlogo_274x122.png' />
                                <div class="email-logo-button">
                                    @Html.RadioButton("logo-selectie", "standaard", !Model.GebruikKlantLogo, new { @name = "logoKeuze" })
                                    <span>standaard logo</span>
                                </div>


                            </span> then I will get the error div cannot be nested inside span

Comment: No, I mean replace the inner divs of the `label`. The `.email-logo-button` and `.email-logo-image`